How is this sentence divided? "を見る感じで" and "やってたみたい"
A:「この写真の相手は俺が入った学校の先生なんだ。小学校」
A:「大学を出てすぐ都の教員試験を経て採用されたって言ってた」
A:「２３、４歳の時は新人だからっていうので１、２年生の持ち上がりで学年全体を見る感じでやってたみたいだ」
B:「学年担当、っていうんですよね、そういうの」
A:「そうだな。やってたみたい、っていうのは俺が見てないからだけど。社会科担当だったよ」
The character is talking about a friend in a picture and explaining that friend life story.
What I'm stumbled is the last sentence, how is divided exactly?
"２３、４歳の時は新人だからっていうので"
Explain they were 23 or 24 and a newcomer so...
"２年生の持ち上がりで学年全体を見る感じでやってたみたいだ」"
I'm not sure what to make of this here. "２年生の持ち上がりで" seems to be as "as first year or second year homeroom teacher"
But how is this sentence exactly divided 学年全体を見る感じでやってたみたいだ?
I'm stumbled in particular on 見る感じでやって. How やってたみたい being used here?


っていうので (=というので) means "(reportedly) because" or "because they say ...".
持ち上がり means looping. See the third definition on jisho.
学年全体を見る in this context means the teacher was taking care of the entire grade level (as 学年担当 = grade-level supervisor) rather than one specific class. Normally, 担任 means being in charge of one class as a homeroom teacher, but this new teacher did not have such a class.
～感じでやってたみたいだ = it seems they were doing in a way ～

感じで carries a sense of "kind of; sort of; like".



All in all:

２３、４歳の時は新人だからっていうので１、２年生の持ち上がりで学年全体を見る感じでやってたみたいだ
When they were 23 or 24, since they were still new, it seems they were sort of taking care of the entire grade level, looping with first and second graders.

